# How do I SELECT such that a group by column has every value from supplied list in another coumn

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In MS SQL Server 2008, have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
   MajorID int NOT NULL REFERENCES ...,
   MinorID int NOT NULL,
   Value   int NOT NULL REFERENCES ...,
   PRIMARY KEY(MajorID, MinorID)
)
```

I also have a set of (Value0, Value1, ...). The goal is to find all such MajorID that have every Value from the set listed at least once. MinorID is not important in this task. The size of set is not predefined, and the set is generated in client application. There's a reasonable limit on its maximum size, say, 64.

What SQL should I use?

Example:

```
MajorID MinorID Value
      1       0     4
      1       1     1
      1       2     3
      1       3     4
      1       4     4
      1       5     5
      1       6     5

      2       0     1

      3       0     1
      3       1     4
```

For value list (1, 4) the answer is (1, 3), because MajorID 1 and 3 have each value listed at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple way:

```
select majorid
from ReportStack
where value in (1, 3)
group by majorid
having count (distinct value) = 2
```

The only maintenance issue with this query is making sure the having clause value (`2` in this query) is the same as size of the target value list.

Comment: Thank you! This is very simple and fitting solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with aggregation, as in this query:

```
select majorid
from t
group by majorid
having COUNT(distinct value) = (select COUNT(distinct value) from t)
```

The `having` clause checks that all values are there for a `majorid`.

This is for *all* values.  If you have a value list, then try this:

```
with valuelist as (
      select 1 as vslue union all
      select 4
)
select majorid
from t join
     valuelist vl
     on t.value = vl.value
group by majorid
having count(distinct value) = (select count(*) from valuelist)
```

Comment: +1 and thank you for helping. I will accept solution from Bohemian as it much better suits the case where the value list is variable-sized and generated in application.